# Generic helper class called from an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, abstract-class

I have some generic helper methods. I would like to be able to call one from within an abstract class but i do not have the derived type to pass into the Generic method. How do i get it? I do not want to make the abstract class a generic too. Is this possible?! here is some code that does not work... :'(

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public bool Save()
    {
        try
        {
            Helper<this.GetType()>.Save(this);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the helper class code

```
public class Helper<T> where T: class
{
    public static bool Save(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.DDBContext.Save<T>(obj);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like more code please ask.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to pass `Helper<Base>.Save(this);`? It seems to be an object that can be saved.

Comment: I hadnt thought of that gimmie a second to see if that works :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter do you know i think you have it, this is Covariance and Contravariance in action isnt it... :D pop it on and i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion, you can also define your helper as an extension method, move the generic type parameter to the method, restrict the type parameter to `Base`, and you can call it from the derived type as though it is derived in the base:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static bool Save<T>(this T obj) where T: Base
    {
        try
        {
            Context.DBContext.Save<T>(obj);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }               
}

public class Derived : Base{}

var x = new Derived();
x.Save();
```

Then you can remove `Base.Save` completely.

Comment: Interesting! let me try

Answer (score 1):

Your abstract base class cannot "know" the type of any derived class.

Delegate the call to your helper method to the derived class(es), e.g. by defining a abstract virtual method in the base class:

```
protected abstract void Save(…);
```

Then instead of calling the helper method directly, invoke this abstract method. Derived classes can override it, *they* will know their own type:

```
sealed class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void Save(…)
    {
        Helper<Derived>.Save(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but then in every derived type i would be repeating the same code. i am trying to avoid this

Comment: @Adween - there isn't another way. this is what OO is all about as well as having abstract classes. an abstract class cannot know the classes that are deriving from it but does somewhat "enforce" the derived classes to override abstract members. you say that in every derived class you would be repeating the code - what code?

Comment: @Adween: Your use of generics more or less *enforces* this. Unless you can pass `Base` as an argument to the generic type parameter `T`, and a `Derived` object as an argument for `Save`'s `obj` parameter, then all of this wouldn't be necessary and you'd always call `Helper<Base>.Save(this)`.

Comment: @stakx Tim got there first i am awaiting his post to mark as correct. The derived type is know by passing Base. i didn't know it would know. very clever :)

Comment: @Adween: No problem. Feel free to accept any answer that you feel was most helpful.